# Angular2-cli not copying shared folder files to dist

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Im using the Angular-cli for my angular 2 project and doing a production build using

```
ng b -prod
```

the project is created using the ng-clig and as i understand all static resources like images should be placed in the **shared** folder

However when examining the dist folder ,it doesn't have any of the images....

Is this a known issue or i need to add something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect understanding of the `shared` folder. It is not a place to put files you wish to have copied to the build output folder. The folder you are looking for is entitled `assets` those files will be copied to the output directory, `dist` for both dev and prod builds.

The shared directory is a place to put common (or shared) portions of your application, whether they be components, directives, pipes, classes or services.

Comment: Thanks for claryfing, its important to clarify that the cli is not creating this folder i created it manually and after that ths dist folder had this relevant files